querySelectorAll won't select all objects
I want to save data from cards. I am saving data from card inputs with contain the same name. Cards added dynamically. querySelectorAll contains data from first card only without data from dynamically added cards.
script.js
var currentCardNumber = 1;

function addCard() {

    currentCardNumber++;
    let newCardHTML = `
                    <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                        <h4 class="card-counter">${currentCardNumber}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body row">
                        <div class="term col">
                            <h3>Term</h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="definition col">
                            <h3>Definition </h3>
                            <input class="form-control w-100" name="definition" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div> `;
    let newCard = document.createElement('div');
    newCard.classList.add('card');
    newCard.classList.add('mt-3');
    newCard.innerHTML = newCardHTML;

    let addNewCard = document.querySelector('.cards');
    let referenceNode = document.getElementById('create-cards');
    addNewCard.insertBefore(newCard, referenceNode);

}
function saveCardDataToServer() {
  let cards = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card) => {

    let term = card.querySelector('input[name="term"]').value.trim();
    let definition = card.querySelector('input[name="definition"]').value.trim();
    if (term && definition) {
      cards.push({
        Term: term,
        Definition: definition
      });
    }
  })
  fetch('/Cards/Create/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cards)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data => {
      if (data.success) {
        console.log("Data successfully saved: ", data);
        window.location.href = "/Cards/Learning";
      } else {
        console.error("Error saving card: ", data.message);
      }
    }))
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let newCard = document.querySelector('.new-card');
  newCard.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addCard();
  });
  document.querySelector('form.cards').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    saveCardDataToServer();
  });
});

View
@model CardList

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quizlet</title>
    <script src="~/js/script.js">
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" asp-append-version="true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/MainStyles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    
</head>

<body>

<main class="main">
  <div class="container">
                <div class="new-module d-flex justify-content-between mt-5">
            <h1>Create new module</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="learning" type="submit">Создать</a>
        </div>

        <div class="card mt-5 p-2 pb-3">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <input class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Enter a name">
        </div>
        <form asp-controller="Cards" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="cards">
            <div class="card mt-6" id="card">
                <div class="header d-flex justify-content-between p-3">
                    <h4 class="card-counter">1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body row">
                    <div class="term col">
                        <h3>Term</h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "term" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="definition col">
                        <h3>Definition </h3>
                        <input class="form-control w-100" name = "definition"  >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-cards" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"/>
        </form>
        <button class="new-card w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4 mt-s rounded-2" style="height: 5rem"  type="button">
            <h3>+ Add card</h3>
        </button>
  </div>

</main>
</body>

</html>

I believe the issue may be related to the addition of dynamic cards.

do you execute document.querySelectorAll('.card') AFTER you execute addCard - because, unlike document.getElementsByClassName the list returned by .querySelectorAll is NOT dynamic

If you click [edit], then the button [<>] then you can create a stacksnippet to show us a [mcve] - please post expanded HTML instead of  asp-controller template

Try putting querySelectorAll After you create cards with addCard()

Please show how you're calling the code with document.querySelectorAll().

@Barmar I edited my question and showed how I'm calling document.querySelectorAll()

There's an extra }) on the 2nd-to-last line of saveCardDataToServer

I can't see any reason why the document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach( would not process all the cards. As long as term and definition are both non-empty in a card, it should add them to the cards array.

If you look for all .card items in the Elements inspector, do you see them?

@Barmar Yes, I see them.

After execute document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach( I get the error  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') in let term = card.querySelector('input[name="term"]').value.trim();

I repeat: If you click [edit], then the button [<>] then you can create a stacksnippet to show us a minimal reproducible example - please post expanded HTML instead of asp-controller template - we can help really fast when we have a running example

That error means that some of the .card elements don't have an input[name="term"] input field. Is it possible you're reusing class="card" in some other parts of your HTML?

If you set the debugger to stop on exceptions, you should be able to click on the card variable in the stack frame. You'll see what it's referring to and can figure out why card.querySelector('input[name="term"]') doesn't find anything.

I apologize to everyone. I thought when I hovered over querySelector and I saw "length: 1" think what this objects array length. When I put the data into the console, I saw all the objects needed in querySelectorAll
